# Embeding an OLE object in PowerPoint from Excel VBA - size and position does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Excel VBA to update PowerPoint presentation. I am trying to embed two excel files into one of the slides and I have set all the parameters but the size and position bit does not seem to be working.

```
MyPresentation.Slides(9).Shapes.AddOLEObject Left:=142, Top:=142, Width:=200, Height:=170, Filename:=Met2FactSheet, _
DisplayAsIcon:=msoTrue, IconLabel:="Metro2 Fact Sheet"
```

The object is embedded but with no sizing at all (as if I have omitted that part of the code).

Comment: Can you include the entire code?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning it to an object variable first, and then try setting the properties.  For example...

```
Set ppShape = MyPresentation.Slides(9).Shapes.AddOLEObject( _
    Filename:=Met2FactSheet, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=msoTrue, _
    IconLabel:="Metro2 Fact Sheet")

With ppShape
    .Left = 142
    .Top = 142
    .Width = 200
    .Height = 170
End With
```

If you're using early binding, you can declare `ppShape` as `PowerPoint.Shape`.  Otherwise, if you're using late binding, you can declare `ppShape` as `Object`.

Hope this helps!